# Unix If file exists, rename

Tags: unix, timestamp, rename

I am working on a UNIX task where i want check if a particular log file is present in the directory or not. If it is present, i would like to rename it by appending a timestamp at the end. The format of the file name is as such: ServiceFileName_0.log

This is what i have so far but it wouldn't rename when i run the script, even though there is a file with the name ServiceFileName_0.log present.

```
renameLogs()
{
   #If a ServiceFileName log exists, rename it

   if [ -f $MY_DIR/logs/ServiceFileName_0.log ]; 
   then
    mv ServiceFileName_0.log ServiceFileName_0.log.%M%H%S
   fi
}
```

Pls Help!

Thanks

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
renameLogs()
{
    if [ -f $MY_DIR/logs/ServiceFileName_0.log ] 
    then mv $MY_DIR/ServiceFileName_0.log $MY_DIR/ServiceFileName_0.log.$(date +%M%H%S)
    fi
}
```

Use the directory prefix consistently.  Also you need to specify the time properly, as shown.

Better, though (less repetition):

```
renameLogs()
{
    logfile="$MY_DIR/logs/ServiceFileName_0.log"
    if [ -f "$logfile" ] 
    then mv "$logfile" "$logfile.$(date +%H%M%S)"
    fi
}
```

NB: I've reordered the format from MMHHSS to the more conventional HHMMSS order.  If you work with date components too, you should seriously consider using the ordering recommended by ISO 8601, which is [YYYY]mmdd.  It groups all the log files for a month together in an `ls` listing, which is usually helpful.  Using ddmm order means that the files for the first of each month are grouped together, then the files for the second of each month, etc.  This is usually less desirable.

Comment: Thanks for that. If i Wanted to replace the time with a string, would this be the correct syntax? mv $MY_DIR/ServiceFileName_0.log $MY_DIR/ServiceFileName_0.log.$("Previous") ?

Comment: The notation `$("Previous")` would execute a command `Previous` and use its output in the rename process.  Without doing anything special, in your original, the backup would contain the literal characters `%H%M%S`; they only have special meaning to a few commands, such as `date`, which is why I added the invocation of `date`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. I also have another file i have to rename the same way but the file name is ServiceFileName_1903.log . The 1903 stands for DDMM and tomorrow would be 2003, 2103 and so on. what would be the generic argument i could put in the IF statement because the number keeps on changing everytime

Comment: Look up the format arguments to [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) with `man date`.  You've got the general idea from the answer above, but the details are described in the man page, and you should know how to use the version on your machine, or how to find it on the web.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to prefix the file name with the `$MY_DIR` path, just like you did in the test.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace this:

```
mv ServiceFileName_0.log ServiceFileName_0.log.%M%H%S
```

with this

```
mv $MY_DIR/logs/ServiceFileName_0.log $MY_DIR/logs/ServiceFileName_0.log.%M%H%S
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your apparent immediate problem, but the `if` construct is wrong: it introduces a [time-of-check to time-of-use race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  *In between* the `if [ -f` check and the `mv`, some other process could come along and change things so you can't move the file anymore even though the check succeeded.

To avoid this class of bugs, always write code that *starts* by attempting the operation you want to do, then if it failed, figure out why.  In this case, what you want is to do nothing if the source file didn't exist, but report an error if the operation failed for any other reason.  There is no good way to do that in portable shell, you need something that lets you inspect `errno`.  I'd probably write this C helper:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s source destination\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    if (rename(argv[1], argv[2]) && errno != ENOENT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "rename '%s' to '%s': %s\n", 
                argv[1], argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
renameLogs()
{
    ( cd "$MY_DIR/logs"
      rename_if_exists ServiceFileName_0.log ServiceFileName_0.log.$(date +%M%H%S)
    )
}
```

The `( cd` construct fixes your immediate problem, and unlike the other suggestions, avoids *another* race in which some other process comes along and messes with the `logs` directory or its parent directories.

Obligatory shell scripting addendum: Always enclose variable expansions in double quotes, except in the rare cases where you *want* the expansion to be subject to word splitting.